# Spree get all taxons from underlying taxonomy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

How to get all taxons that are children of a certain taxonomy.

I retrieve the taxonomy like this:

```
Spree::Taxonomy.find_by_machine_name('product_categories')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spree::Taxonomy [has_many :taxons](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.3/core/app/models/spree/taxonomy.rb#L5) so you should be able to do:

```
Spree::Taxonomy.find_by_machine_name('product_categories').taxons
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use deprecated dynamic finders.  Instead I would use:
```Spree::Taxonomy.find_by(machine_name: 'product_categories').taxons```